# ReAgentC Application Error: Continue factory reset?

Tags: windows, windows-10, reset, factory-defaults

I have a Notebook (Samsung Ativ Book 9) running on Windows 10 and I am trying to do a factory reset with Samsung Recovery (Boot + F4). While loading I get an Application Error:

> ReAgentc.exe - Application Error
>   The Application was unable to start correctly (0x0000279). Click OK to close this Application.

When clicking OK another error pops up with the error code 0xc0000279. After this the recovery program coninues and I can choose a backup to restore from. I'm a little scared to go through with the recovery agent, since I don't want to blow my system. What do you guys think? Should I try to go through with the recovery despite the error messages?

Comment: 0xc0000279 = STATUS_IO_REPARSE_TAG_NOT_HANDLED = The layered file system driver for this IO tag did not handle it when needed. before trying the recovery stopp all 3rd party tools/drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably noone can tell you about the risk of running the recovery after you got those error messages. Of course it might go all well with no further errors, and recovery passes cleanly, but it might be as well that recovery crashes in the middle of the process and you'd end up with no working operating system at all.

I'd advise you to not continue to run the recovery with that app, since there are signs that the application is broken and recovery might fail. Try to get an update of Samsung Recovery somewhere. Do you have to use Samsung Recovery? Why not use the regular Windows recovery? It would probably be even better, since Windows recovery won't install any bloatware on your computer afterwards.

### Use Windows 10 recovery

There are many options to do this, the easiest is to insert your installation media (e.g. a USB drive or DVD that came with your computer, or a USB drive or DVD you bought Windows on), and boot from it (make it temporarily the first boot priority in BIOS).

In case you don't have your installation media anymore, you can create a new one at the [Windows 10 ISO download site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). Grab the ISO image from there, and burn it to a DVD, or copy it's content onto a USB drive. You can also search for "create a recovery device" on a working Windows 10 computer.

When you started your computer in recovery mode using either your installation media or a recovery device, you have to enter some settings like language, and then select "Reset this PC". Windows will offer you multiple options to do so. Refer to [this Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options) for further information.